# Create Responsive Plot in Julia

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, graphics, julia

Okey, I am so lost in here that I cannot make even a concrete question, so I shall be very general and hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

I am producing some scientific plots in Julia with PyPlot, and I am very satisfied with the results ( adequate and clear estetics and I can handle the syntax to create very complex images ). But I need to produce a so called "heatmap" ( a 2D bitmap image ) in which the user should be able to select a set of points of the image with the mouse. The selection, which will be confined to a discrete grid, shall be stored in some Iterable, an Array or similar. I have no idea where to start, if at the same PyPlot library or using something like Gtk or GtkReact (this last one I couldn't get the examples running). Can I be pointed to the right direction?

Comment: The Makie package also offers capturing interaction. There's an example here: http://juliaplots.org/MakieReferenceImages/gallery//edit_polygon/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`PyPlot` is an interface to Python's matplotlib which makes static plots.
Use `Plotly` inside a Jupyter notebook instead:  https://plot.ly/julia/heatmaps/,

Comment: I do not need the plot to change, it can be static. I need to be able to retrieve the coordinates of the points I click.

Comment: This is exactly the case you can find in Plotly tutorial that I linked to. However if you need just the coordinates running from Julia REPL console code such us  `PyPlot.imshow(rand(4,4))` will spawn a matplotlib window that shows coordinates where hovering over the graph.

Comment: Mmmmm, I'll give it a try, though I will probably have to recreate the whole graph in Plotly. In PyPlot I have more issues: if I use it inside Jupyter no coordinates are shown. If on the terminal, it crashes. Always. No matter what I plot.

Comment: Crashing: (1) make sure that `using PyPlot` is called before any matplotlib command (it is possible to call marplotlib directly via `PyCall` but then it crashes. (2) you can use with Python either Julia in-built Anaconda or external Anaconda. If one of those configuration crashes test the other (for more details see https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl). Normally the in-built Anaconda works perfectly. Regarding rewriting consider using `Plots.jl` that makes it easy to change plotting backends.